# Hide object(s) behind invisible wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to make a box using cubes and make them transparent which i have achieved with this shader code:

```
Shader "Custom/InvisibleMask" {    
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent+1"}
        Pass {
            Blend Zero One
        }
}
```

Now i want to be able to have a sphere (or any other object) be visible like normally but disappear when it going inside of the box.

As of now i have this as a script added to my object (Sphere):

```
void Start () {
    Renderer[] renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    foreach (Renderer r in renderers)
        r.material.renderQueue = 3002;
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me and i dont know how to solve this since shaders are really not my strongsuit.

If anybody could help me, that would be great.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After long digging I figured out that for some reason the renderQueue was set to 2002 instead of 3002, no idea why this happened but I changed it manually in the inspector and that fixed it